# Why doesn't Google Guava Preconditions's checkArgument return a value?

Tags: java, guava, argument-passing

I really love how guava library allows simple one-liners for checking for null:

```
public void methodWithNullCheck(String couldBeNull) {
    String definitelyNotNull = checkNotNull(couldBeNull);
    //...
}
```

sadly, for simple argument check you need at least two lines of code:

```
public void methodWithArgCheck(String couldBeEmpty) {
    checkArgument(!couldBeEmpty.isEmpty());
    String definitelyNotEmpty = couldBeEmpty;
    //...
}
```

however it is possible to add method which could do argument check *and* return a value if check successful. Below is an example of check and how it could be implemented:

```
public void methodWithEnhancedArgCheck(String couldBeEmpty) {
    String definitelyNotEmpty = EnhancedPreconditions.checkArgument(couldBeEmpty, !couldBeEmpty.isEmpty());
    //...
}

static class EnhancedPreconditions {
    public static <T> T checkArgument(T reference, boolean expression) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        return reference;
    }
}
```

I just was wondering is that by design and if it is worth to put feature request for that.

**EDIT**: @Nizet, yeah, checks in methods could be clumsy. However checks in constructors for nulls looks really good and saves a lot of time spent on debugging NPEs:

```
public class SomeClassWithDependency {

    private final SomeDependency someDependency;

    public SomeClassWithDependency(SomeDependency someDependency) {
        this.someDependency = checkNotNull(someDependency);
    }

    //...
```

**EDIT**: Accepting Nizet's answer because I agree with him on side-effects and consistency reasoning. 
Also if you take a look into Xaerxess comment it looks like that causing confusion amongst other developers as well.

Comment: In addition to your example with `checkArgument(T ref, boolean expr)`, recently there was an [issue #1038](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1038) discussing `Preconditions.checkArgument(T ref, Predicate<T> test)` which was rejected. You can always create `Preconditions2` class with your own methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've never understood is why `checkNotNull()` returns its argument in the first place:

```
public void foo(String bar) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(bar);
    // here, you're sure that bar is not null. 
    // No need to use another variable or to reassign bar to the result 
    // of checkNotNull()
}
```

I personally ignore the result of `checkNotNull()`, as above. And this makes things consistent with the other checks which return void.

The only advantage I see is that you can do something like that, but I find it less readable than doing it in two separate lines:

```
public String trim(String bar) {
    return Preconditions.checkNotNull(bar).trim();
}
```

So, in short, I agree with you that the API is somewhat inconsistent, but I would prefer for all the methods to return void. A method should either have a side effect, or return something, but doing both should be avoided generally. Here, the goal of the method is to have a side effect: throwing an exception.

EDIT:

Your example is indeed a more valid explanation of why returning the argument is useful. But I would still have favored consistency and cleanness instead of this possibility of checking and assigning in a single line.

Comment: I would not do things like `Preconditions.checkNotNull(bar).trim()` instead of simple `bar.trim()`. In both cases you get the same NPE, so the test buys you nothing and you're only obscuring a simple thing. `checkNotNull` is intended for failing fast, so you avoid possibly incorrect partial execution of a method and get a shorter stack trace.

Comment: If you write it as: `return checkNotNull(bar, "bar may not be null").trim();`, it starts making sense to do it. Anyway, I'm not saying it should be done. To the contrary: I think `checkNotNull()` should return void.

Comment: @JBNizet I respect the quality of your argumentation, which is why I won't downvote. In my opinion the checknotNull method is a very good choice for returning the variable and I wish there were more methods like that (e.g. `someInt / Ints.checkNoneZero(someOtherInt)`. I think it's a nice way to highlight important code requirements without making methods unnecessarily long. I think it makes code more, not less readable. On the contrary, I don't see the point of using the method at all in your first example.

Comment: I've got 1 usecase where checkNotNull() returns its argument. The call to superclass constructor:
`super(Preconditions.checkNotNull(param1))`

Answer (score 24):

The biggest single reason that `checkNotNull` returns its argument is so it can be used in constructors, like so:

```
public Foo(Bar bar) {
  this.bar = checkNotNull(bar);
}
```

But the main reason that `checkArgument` doesn't do something similar is that you'd have to pass the argument separately anyway, and it just doesn't seem worth it -- especially with more complicated precondition checks, which can sometimes be more readable on their own line.  Just because something *can* be a one-liner doesn't mean that it *should* be, if it doesn't increase readability.

Comment: I didn't know it did return the parameter... doing a "Code Golf" refactor :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use valid4j with hamcrest-matchers instead (found on Maven Central as org.valid4j:valid4j)

For preconditions and postconditions:

```
import static org.valid4j.Assertive.*;

this.myField = require(argument, notNullValue());
this.myInteger = require(x, greaterThan(0));
...
return ensure(result, isValid());
```

For input validation:

```
import static org.valid4j.Validation.*;


validate(argument, isValid(), otherwiseThrowing(InvalidException.class));
```

Links:

- http://www.valid4j.org/
- https://github.com/helsing/valid4j